# How I display post of the post type group by year of post?

Tags: customization, query

I want to get all posts from my custom post type in groups by posts of each year.

- 2017 (5)
- 2016 (9)
- 2015 (7)
- 2014 (19)
- 2013 (3)

Comment: What is the purpose of the grouping? To place them in different sections of the page? To add Year headings between results? To count posts per year?

Comment: this is exactly what the archive widget does, did you try looking at that code?

Answer (score 1):

You can get list with below code :

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=yearly&format=option&post_type=resources&show_post_count=true');  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return an array of arrays, by year, with a count.

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'cpt_post_type'
];
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$posts_by_year = [];

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $year = get_the_date('Y');
        $posts_by_year[$year][] = ['title' => get_the_title(), 'link' => get_the_permalink()];
        $posts_by_year[$year]['count'] = count($posts_by_year[$year]);
    }
}
```

You could then foreach the $posts_by_year to iterate through them in the view. I would also wrap the above in to a function.

Comment: I think this way of doing it is quite useful as you can add what you need in to the array for each post, passing only what you need further down the stack.